# "<Story: title>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I added code, so the user can connect story maximum with 2 genres, when I try to save story it brings error in title.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alias = slugify(self.title, 'ru')

        return super(Story, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.genre.count() > 2:
            raise ValidationError('Error')
        super(Story, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the problem is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i think that story should be pre saved, to take his id for checking the number of genres

Answer (score 1):

Both objects need to be saved first in order to get `id` values, before the many-to-many relationship can be set.  This is because the many-to-many relationship is stored using a third database table which holds all the (story.id, genre.id) pairs.  You want something like:

```
my_genre = Genre(name='Fable')
my_genre.save()
my_story = Story(title='The Tortoise and the Hare')
my_story.save()

# now that my_genre.id and my_story.id are defined, the many-to-many relationship can be set:
my_story.genre.set([my_genre])
my_story.save()
```